# How to overlay text on image in opencv without modifying the underlying matrix

Tags: image, opencv, text, overlay

I need a way to overlay text on opencv image without actually modifying the underlying image. For example inside a while loop i create a random point for each iteration and I want to display it. If I use puttext the matrix gets overwritten with the added text in each cycle.

**My questions is how to overlay text on opencv image without modifying the underlying matrix.** I know I could use a temporary copy of the original image and upload it every time. However I want to avoid it.

My attempt(which fails) is as below:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{

    RNG rng( 0xFFFFFFFF );
    cv::Mat image(480, 640, CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(0,255,0));

    int fontFace = FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL;
    double fontScale_small=1.5;
    double fontScale_large=10.;
    std::string text="X";

    Point p;

    while(1)
    {

        p.x = rng.uniform( 0, 639 );
        p.y = rng.uniform( 0, 479 );

        putText(image, "X", p, fontFace, 1, Scalar(0,0,255), 2);

        imshow("IMAGE", image);
    waitKey(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is your example representative? There are better methods for drawing markers on an image, rather than writing an `X`, e.g. `drawMarker()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are on OpenCV 3+ and have built OpenCV with Qt, then you can use the highgui functions on the Qt GUI window to overlay text, instead of actively modifying your image. See [`displayOverlay()`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/d46/group__highgui__qt.html#ga704e0387318cd1e7928e6fe17e81d6aa). You can also simply change the status bar text, which is sometimes more useful (so that you don't cover the image or have to deal with color clashes) with [`displayStatusBar()`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/d46/group__highgui__qt.html#gac56ae86269eb4fbd9c8d8cb7babfbf64). However, note that `displayOverlay()` does not allow you to give specific positions for your text.

Without QT support, I don't believe this is possible in OpenCV. You'll need to either modify your image via `putText()` or `addText()`, or roll your own GUI window that you can overlay text on.

Answer (score 0):

You can output your text on black image, then make XOR with source image for put your text, and the second XOR will clear your text from source image.

Comment: In case anyone doubts this, XOR is an associative operation, so `A XOR B XOR B` is `A XOR (B XOR B)`. Since `B XOR B` is 0, we have `A XOR 0` which is simply `A`. So XORing your image with the text image twice will restore it. On the other hand, if you draw the text as white, the XOR color may not be what you expect---it will invert the bits, and for e.g. 127 and 128 are bit inverses (so it would draw text colored 128 over an image area that had values of 127, which would not be readable).